# reading in data from clipboard ignoring first line

Tags: r

Say I have this data:

```
20
yyyy    month   tmax    tmin
1908    January 5.0 -1.4
1908    February    7.3 1.9
1908    March   6.2 0.3
1908    April   Missing_1   2.1
1908    May Missing_2   7.7
1908    June    17.7    8.7
1908    July    Missing_3   11.0
1908    August  17.5    9.7
1908    September   16.3    8.4
1908    October 14.6    8.0
1908    November    9.6 3.4
1908    December    5.8 Missing_4
1909    January 5.0 0.1
1909    February    5.5 -0.3
1909    March   5.6 -0.3
1909    April   12.2    3.3
1909    May 14.7    4.8
1909    June    15.0    7.5
1909    July    17.3    10.8
1909    August  18.8    10.7
```

I can read it into R using:

```
data <- read.table(file = "clipboard", sep = " ", header = FALSE)
```

However this does not give me what I ultimately want. I want to skip the `20` and read in the data.

How can I go about doing this?

Edit:

```
d <- c("
20
yyyy    month   tmax    tmin
1908    January 5.0 -1.4
1908    February    7.3 1.9
1908    March   6.2 0.3
1908    April   Missing_1   2.1
1908    May Missing_2   7.7
1908    June    17.7    8.7
1908    July    Missing_3   11.0
1908    August  17.5    9.7
1908    September   16.3    8.4
1908    October 14.6    8.0
1908    November    9.6 3.4
1908    December    5.8 Missing_4
1909    January 5.0 0.1
1909    February    5.5 -0.3
1909    March   5.6 -0.3
1909    April   12.2    3.3
1909    May 14.7    4.8
1909    June    15.0    7.5
1909    July    17.3    10.8
1909    August  18.8    10.7  

")
```

I can usually read data using:

```
df2 <- read.table(text = "
          -9 -9 -9  1 1 1 
           0 -9  0  4 3 2
          -9 -9 -9  1 2 3
           0  0  8  6 6 0
           0  0  0 -2 0 0
           0  0  1  2 4 0",
           header = FALSE)
```

Comment: there is `skip` argument

Comment: There is an argument `skip = 1`.

Comment: Thanks! This worked: `data <- read.table(file = "clipboard", strip.white=T, sep='', header = TRUE, skip = 1)`

Comment: One additional comment, what if I did not want to have the data copied into my clipboard each time. How can I read it from a string or like from my edit?

Answer (score 0):

We can use the `skip` argument

```
data <- read.table(file = "clipboard", strip.white=TRUE, sep='',
       header = TRUE, skip = 1)
```

---

If we want to read from string, use the `textConnection`

```
df1 <- read.table(textConnection("20
yyyy    month   tmax    tmin
1908    January 5.0 -1.4
1908    February    7.3 1.9
1908    March   6.2 0.3
1908    April   Missing_1   2.1
1908    May Missing_2   7.7
1908    June    17.7    8.7
1908    July    Missing_3   11.0
1908    August  17.5    9.7
1908    September   16.3    8.4
1908    October 14.6    8.0
1908    November    9.6 3.4
1908    December    5.8 Missing_4
1909    January 5.0 0.1
1909    February    5.5 -0.3
1909    March   5.6 -0.3
1909    April   12.2    3.3
1909    May 14.7    4.8
1909    June    15.0    7.5
1909    July    17.3    10.8
1909    August  18.8    10.7"), skip = 1, header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```